# latex: uniform font size (font of a given size) in the formula, regardless of the content of the formula

Tags: fonts, latex, size, formula

Tell me how to make the font size of a formula be the same throughout the formula.

If you use the standard way of writing a formula, then in continued fractions and some other entries the font size starts to change, which is very bad

For example:

```
\begin{multline*}
\begin{split}
1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{1+x}}}
\end{split}
\end{multline*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting a `c`ontinued `frac`tion, for which there exists `\cfrac{<num>}{<denom>}`. So you can use

```
\[
  1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{3 + \cfrac{1}{1 + x}}}
\]
```

In general, TeX will set nested `\frac`s using `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`. If you want to force the regular `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle` font in a fraction, you can use `\dfrac` or `\tfrac`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  1 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{3 + \frac{1}{1 + x}}}
\]

\[
  1 + \dfrac{1}{2 + \dfrac{1}{3 + \dfrac{1}{1 + x}}}
\]

\[
  1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{3 + \cfrac{1}{1 + x}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

solution:

use `\cfrac` instead of `\frac`